# How do we get this by partial summation formula?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, summation-by-parts

[image]
Above image is taken from Selberg's paper on Elementary proof of prime number theorem. I couldn't apply [partial summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Statement) to get this form. I think first we have to complete the two summations above to include all naturals less than $x$, not only those which are product of two primes. But I couldn't proceed then. Please help.